# How to explain that Observable.of(Math.random()) always returns the same value?

Tags: javascript, caching, rxjs

I'm not really sure how to explain it. The observable returned by of() method is not multicast.
If we'd do sth like the following:

```
const obs = of(Math.random()).pipe(tap(()=>console.log('side effect'));
obs.subscribe(console.log);
obs.subscribe(console.log);
obs.subscribe(console.log);
```

We'd see 3 side effects, but 3 also equal values. Why? Normally observables are recalculated on each subscription.

e.g.

```
new Observable(observer => observer.next(Math.random()))
```

would return 3 different values. 
Why does an observable created with a static 'of' method behave differently? I'm not sure how to explain it. Does it have sth to do with observables caching?

EDIT
Here's the small example that helped me prove, that 'of' observables are indeed loaded on demand.

```
const obs = of(undefined).pipe(
    map(() => Math.random())
);
```

or even

```
const obs = of(Math.random).pipe(
    map(random => random())
);
```

Comment: That is probably because you're passing to the `of` function the result of calling `Math.random()` not the function itself.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number. What is supposed to change when that number is _"recalculated"_?

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a random value and is immediately evaluated. So `of(Math.random())` is basically like `of(0.123456)` (or whatever random value is produced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value passed to `of` is prepared when the code is read. This is only a JS thing nothing related to RxJs in particular. Even if you don't subscribe to the observable. Ex:

```
const MyMathRandom = () => {
  console.log('MyMathRandom has been run');
  return Math.random();
}

const test = of(MyMathRandom())
```

Will display in the console `MyMathRandom has been run`.

In your case, you want to function to be executed **lazily** and there's an operator for that: [defer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer)

If you update your code to:

```
const source = defer(() => of(Math.random()))

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The output will be what you're looking for. Ex:

```
0.20757387233599833
0.6417609881625241
0.09756371489129778
```

Live demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jymadr

Answer (score 3):

If you were to call, say, `of(0.5)`, then `of` would see that you passed it 0.5 and creates an observable based on that. Each new subscription will cause the observable to emit the value (0.5) and then complete.

If you changed that to `of(0.25 * 2)`, then `of` still sees that you passed it 0.5, and so it behaves exactly the same. A calculation did happen before hand to create the 0.5, but `of` knows nothing about that.

And if you change it to `of(Math.random())` and by chance the calculated value is 0.5, the behavior is again exactly the same. `of` got passed a 0.5, so it creates an observable that spits out 0.5 and then completes. It has no idea how that 0.5 was calculated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer there. But I think he's just looking for `defer`. See my answer